# Make a new array method that transforms array values into upper case:

Tags: javascript

```
Array.prototype.myUcase = function() {
 for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
  this[i] = this[i].toUpperCase();
  }
};
```

but strings are immutable. Why does reassigning value to the string works in this case?

Comment: It's replacing each index of the array with a new string

Comment: But it's still re-assigning and changing the original array right? Sorry I know it's stupid, but I am really confused

Comment: Yes, because arrays are mutable. `toUpperCase` creates a new string and assigns it to the specific index of the array. If you just did `for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { this[i].toUpperCase() }` the data at `this[i]` will not be updated

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, but the array you're processing is not. If you need your prototype method to return a new array, like `map` or `reduce` does, you need to first make a copy of the original array, and then work on that.

Something along the lines of this (pseudo-code):

```
Array.prototype.something = function() {
  var copy = [...this];
  // do operations on copy
  return copy;
}
```

Note, that the spread operator (`...`) only makes a new reference, not a "deep clone".

Comment: `new` is a keyword

Comment: Right, as I said it's pseudo code ;) Corrected for .... correctness :)